# how to handle case when ng-repeat object has null json object?

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="documents in documentations">
    <td>{{documents.document_name}}</td>                
    <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='secondTrdForm.documentationId' ng-true-value='{{documents.documentationId}}' ng-false-value='' name='docs[]' id='chkId_{{documents.documentationId}}' />
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the documentations object is empty, I get angularjs error doc[0] is undefined.

How can I check if documentations list object is empty and avoid angularjs error ?

error returned in angular:

```
Error: data[0] is undefined
@http://localhost:82/?p=secondtrd_product&cp_id=101175&wf_id=100229:403:17
$http/promise.success/<@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:9971:11
processQueue@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:14454:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:14470:27
    $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:82/angular/    angular.js:15719:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:82/angula    r/angular.js:15530:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:82/angular    /angular.js:15824:13
done@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:10263:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:10435:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:10376:1
```

Comment: Error isn't coming from view. Need to look closer at error to see where it is thrown and show controller code.View will fail silently when repeater array is null

Comment: place inside `<div ng-if="documentations"></div>`

Comment: @aarosil that is un necessary and will create an un needed child scope

Comment: Below is the angular error.
Error: data[0] is undefined
@http://localhost:82/?p=secondtrd_product&cp_id=101175&wf_id=100229:403:17
$http/promise.success/<@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:9971:11
processQueue@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:14454:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:14470:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:82/angular/angular.js:15719:16

Comment: don't put blobs of code in comments, format them in update in question

Comment: Please include your javascript.  Especially the lines where this fails.  `@http://localhost:82/?p=secondtrd_product&cp_id=101175&wf_id=100229:403:17` wherever that is.

Comment: Hey @Charlieftgl if <div ng-if="documentations"></div> is not a good idea. Can you please give me better way to do resolve this ?

Comment: no because the problem has nothing to do with the view, it has to do with your request code for data in controller or service which you haven't shown. Also inspect your request in browser dev tools network tab to see what is being sent and returned

Comment: @ryanyuyu javascript is pretty simple its just an ajax call that returns list of documents. Actually code works file if the "documentations" as something. Some time it returns null. And I just want to check if its null, do not print anything.
    $http.post("?ajax=loadDocumentation",pObj).success(function(data){
        $scope.documentations = data;        
    });

Comment: @AashisBinodKhanal once again, please edit your question instead of adding these details in comments.

Comment: Explain more about `sometimes returns null`. What exactly gets returned? If it's null don't assign it to scope...simple fix. Or better set it as `[]` then can check length in view using `ng-if` and put "no results" in view

Comment: @charlietfl thanks acually it worked with ng-if and having condition to set the variable as []